# python set() in LabVIEW

Tags: python, set, porting, labview

Porting some python code to LabVIEW and I run across the python set().  Is there a better way of representing this in LabVIEW other than with a variant or array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest would be to use variant attributes.

You use a "dummy" variant to store key/value pairs. The Variant Set Attribute function prevents duplicates (overwrites existing with output indicating replaced) and the Get function will return all key/value pairs if no key value is specified.

The underlying functions use a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), making lookups very fast for large datasets.

http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Darren-s-Weekly-Nugget-10-09-2006/m-p/425269

Comment: Hadn't thought of using them that way.  I was using an array of variants, but that's clearly more efficient, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall LabView don't include  analog of set() from box. Therefore you must create VI for delete duplicate values from Array. I hope below two links will help for you.

[Remove duplicate values in an Array](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-4882)
[Delete, Collapse, Array Duplicate Elements](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Delete-Collapse-Array-Duplicate-Elements/td-p/1737798)

Furthermore you can take some HashSet realisation ([one](https://github.com/avsej/hashset.c), [two](http://people.ucsc.edu/~jinnis/), [three](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-1762/libbanshee/engine/)) and [call it from LabView](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2719/en/).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't call a C module -- needs to be pure LV.  I think I will just implement my own class.  May put it up on the NI forums later.  Thanks, though.